# Why does ping return .1 and .10?

Tags: networking, ping

this is not really a problem, but I'd like to know the reason behind this behavior.

When I ping any IP (eg 8.8.8.8) I get:

```
...
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=23283 ttl=120 time=50.4 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=23284 ttl=120 time=**43.1 ms**
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=23285 ttl=120 time=43.0 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=23290 ttl=120 time=**27.10 ms**
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=23291 ttl=120 time=28.0 ms
...
```

As you can see there is an entry with a decimal of .10 and another with .1 (without the trailing 0).
They should be the same, why the difference?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What version of `ping` (or at least, what version of `iputils-ping`) is this? Looking at the source, the precision should go from 0 to 3 places depending on the size of the time field - but as far as I can tell the breaks should be at multiples of 10 (i.e. < 1ms, < 10ms, < 100ms)

Comment: inetutils-ping/cosmic 2:1.9.4-3build1 amd64